# Extracting data from text file with differing delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file that I need to split into an array, each element of the array will contain data for 1 person. I will then use Regex (C#) to extract all the data for that person. The problem I am having is matching the start of each person as the pattern changes within the file. See below:

A simplified version of the data is below:

Address FirstName \r\nSurname NHS No Age = 44\r\n
Address FirstName\r\n Surname NHS No 12345\r\n
Address FirstName\r\n Surname NHS No Age = 35\r\n
Address FirstName \r\nSurname NHS No 54321\r\n

As you can see there are linebreaks within the file so StreamReader.Readline() method probably won't work.
The address name and surname fields are fixed length fields and I can extract these using substring. I can split into the array of people once I have a consistent marker for the start/end of each person.

I need to use Regex.Replace to add a start of person marker, then use this marker to split into the array. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Why do you "need to use Regex.Replace"? Perhaps there are other solutions. Can you post several _complete_ examples of a person record, so we can see what you are dealing with?

Comment: Sorry I can't post the file information as it contains protected information. I can quite easily get all the patient data using Regex. Before I do this I need an array of people that I can loop through.
The end of each person ends either in:
12345\r\n OR  Age = 25\r\n
I can use the matches above to split into the array but I'm not sure how to do this when the start marker varies. Sorry I can't give more info than this and thanks for you quick response.

Comment: Then post a redacted version.

Comment: Address FirstName Surname NHS No  //Person1
Age = 44\r\n
Address FirstName Surname NHS No // person 2
12345\r\n

The address name and surname fields are fixed length fields and I can extract these using substring. I can split into the array of people once I have a consistent marker for the start/end of each person.

Comment: @Freefall Steve: In other words, the "end of each person" always ends in a newline? Or a number, followed by a new line? Why not simply read the file line by line, and then parse each line separately?

Comment: How does the person details begin?  Maybe you can split based on that instead?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the details to the question, not to a comment where it might not get read.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. <sub>Jamie Zawinski</sub>

Are you convinced that regex will make your code easier to write, read and maintain?

Consider using [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) instead.

Comment: I would suggest adding this quotation in the regex tag info.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it looks like each row represents a single entity, regardless of the nuances of the format. For start, you could read the file line by line, and split each line into words using `String.Split`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("addresses.txt")) 
{
     string line;
     // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
     // the file is reached.
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
     {
         string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');

         // variant 1: Address FirstName Surname NHS No //Person1 Age = 44
         // variant 2: Address FirstName Surname NHS No //person 2 12345

         Console.Writeline("Address: ", tokens[0]);
         Console.Writeline("First name: ", tokens[1]);

         // etc.
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, doesn't the ReadLine() method only read up to a line break? If so will I be able to use it with line breaks mixed in with the data items? See below:


Address FirstName\r\n Surname \r\nNHS No Age = 44\r\n 

Address FirstName\r\n Surname \r\nNHS No  12345\r\n

Address FirstName\r\n Surname\r\n NHS No Age = 30\r\n

Address FirstName\r\n Surname\r\n NHS No  56789\r\n